# LAMP settings – PHP and multiple DB connections with mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, mysql-connect

I was assigned to maintain prehistoric PHP application, which uses some 'phpDB' class written by Joe Thong, last updated in 1999. This application connects to two different databases on the same server, taking some data from one and another from the second one.

Now, the limit of `mysql_connect` is, that it uses the same connection resource for new connections. Therefore, if I use following code:

```
$db1 = new phpDB()->connect(/* db1data, database 'one' */);
$db2 = new phpDB()->connect(/* db2data, database 'one' */);
$data = $db1->query($somequery);
```

**EDIT NOTE:** `new phbDB()->connect` just sets some internal values and does standard `mysql_connect` without `$new_link` parameter.

Now, the problem is, that the `$query` is **run over the database two**, because it has rewritten previous connection.

This can be solved by using `true` as fourth parameter in `mysql_connect`. The thing is, I would rather **not** rewrite something in 12 years old library (because of pure fear of how it will react on live server), and also it works without that fourth parameter on live server. However, me not being server guru, I was unable to locate the proper directive in the server configuration to switch on my local MAMP configuration, to be closer to emulate live enviroment.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

**EDIT**: wrapper itself:
phpDB.php – *db wrapper* – http://scrp.at/wd
phpDB-mysql.php – *mysql specific code* – http://scrp.at/we

Comment: What's your goal? Adding new queries to the app? Since you said your two databases are on the same server, perhaps it's enough to use one call to `mysql_connect()` and thereafter use `mysql_select_db()`?

Comment: I think you have this wrong somehow.  You should not be able to do `$db1->query`.  `mysql_connect()` returns an ID to a database connection.  From there you can run `mysql_query("SELECT...", $db1);`, and the second parameter specifies the database.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: My goal is to recreate live enviroment this app runs in as close as possible without rewriting every db using file OR that prehistoric db wrapper.

Comment: @Brad: I have used standard PHP code although I stated that app is using very old DB wrapper. I edited the code to closer resemble what it does.

Comment: @Adam, that makes much more sense now... those details were important.  Thank you for correcting it.

Comment: @Brad: I also posted contents of that wrapper itself

Comment: @Adam, looking at this source code, it is using `_connectionID` appropriately in the execute function.  I don't however see your `query` function.

Comment: @Brad: well, the execute does the standard mysql_query on line 189. Whatever, I'll set `$new_link` to `'true'` and hope it'll work on live server. Thanks Brad

Comment: `$new_link` won't be quite what you are looking for.  Where is the `query` method itself?  Yes, I understand that `execute` calls `mysql_query`, but that one is fine.  I suspect wherever `query` is defined in this class, they left out `_connectionID`.

Comment: @Brad - it actually is working now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to fix this is by modifying that `query` method.

Somewhere inside it is calling `mysql_query()`.  All you have to do is add a second parameter which includes a reference to the internal variable containing the MySQL connection reference.

This is speculation because you haven't posted any of the code, but I think you will see something like this:

**Old**

```
function query($thequery) {
    mysql_query($thequery);
    ....
}
```

**Change it to this**

```
function query($thequery) {
    mysql_query($thequery, $this->dbreference);
    ....
}
```

Whatever "dbreference" is called in your class, I have no idea.  Look for whatever variable is set when `mysql_connect` is called.

Comment: it's called $this->_referenceID and it's reused multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

**Have a look at the following pages:**

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

By filling the new_link parameter you can add a new connection.

**For example:**

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password', 'link1');
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password', 'link2');

mysql_query($query, 'link1'); //query on database 1
mysql_query($query, 'link2'); //query on database 2
```

Comment: I know about this possibility, the problem is, that `mysql_connect` is wrapped in 12 years old open source db class, and I'm just scared I'll break something.

Comment: I think you will be fine. I use this myself. It has not been deprecated yet :-)

Comment: I'm not scared of the parameter itself, rather what it does with that old wrapper and server configuration that allows something, that shouldn't be possible (i.e. connecting to multiple DBs without $new_link data).

Comment: "scared" .. its just a little code, make a buckup of the file and edit, if you mess up just overwrite it again and all is well. stop being a baby :)